# modinfo doesn't change after rmmod

Tags: kernel-modules

I am attempting to install a new version of a kernel module. To this end, I attempted to remove the old module with `rmmod mod`. This gave no output. When I tried `modinfo mod`, however, I received the same result I did before calling `rmmod`. What am I missing?

Comment: check `lsmod` before removing and then check again after removing. See if rmmod actually removed the module.

Comment: I see in `lsmod` that the module was removed. However, if `modinfo` doesn't update, how do I know if the loaded version is the one I want?

Comment: `modinfo` fetches the list of known modules by reading the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.*` files, which are usually updated with `depmod`. Try putting your module in that directory and running `depmod -a` and see if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`modinfo` does not care whether the module is loaded or not - if you give it a module name (instead of a full pathname to a `.ko` file), it finds the **module file on disk** based on the current `/etc/modprobe.d` configuration and reports information on it.

So if you already replaced the old module in `/lib/modules/...` with a new version before running your first `modinfo`, it has probably been reporting information on the new version all along! That's why running `rmmod` did not change anything in the `modinfo` output.

If you want to know the version of a kernel module that is currently loaded (as opposed to what's on disk), use `cat /sys/module/<module_name>/version`.